# Product Measure - proof

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu), (Y,\mathscr{B},\nu)$ be two finite measure spaces and $m$ a measure on $\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}$ such that $m(A\times B)=\mu(A)\nu(B)$ where $A\in \mathscr{A}, B\in \mathscr{B}$. Prove that $\mathscr{M}:=\{X\subset \mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}|(u\times \nu)(X)=m(X)\}$ is a monoton class and every measurable rectangle is in $\mathscr{M}$. This proves that $\mathscr{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and is equal to $\mathscr{A}\times\mathscr{B}$. Try to extend your proof for  $\sigma$-finite measure spaces.

Comment: Have anyone an idea how to show the both properties?